# Nativescript fetch from remote, method should wait before return

Tags: angular, typescript, fetch, nativescript

It about a nativescript 7 - angular mobile project.

The method (getMyItemsFromDbRemote) below is returning when called an empty Array which is correct according with the asynchronous principles, so I'm not claiming this.

However, my question is how can modify this method to wait the fetch to return before the method itself return.

Expected result aftwards is:

Length of MyItems 1 = 5

Length of MyItems 2 = 5

instead of

Length of MyItems 2 = 0

Length of MyItems 1 = 5

Notice: The fetch method is described here: https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/fetch

```
    getMyItemsFromDbRemote(loading:boolean): ObservableArray<MyItem> {
    
                let myItems: MyItem[] = [];
                
                fetch(this.serverUrlGET)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((r) => {
                        // r contain 5 elements
                        myItems = this.onGetDataSuccess(r); // the method onGetDataSuccess return an array of MyItem objects ==> MyItem[];
                        console.log("Length of MyItems 1 = " + myItems.length);
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
    
                loading = false;
    
                console.log("Length of MyItems 2 = " + myItems.length);
                return new ObservableArray(myItems);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to return the fetch's Promise and return the `ObservableArray` from within that. Something like this:

```js
getMyItemsFromDbRemote(loading:boolean): Promise<void | ObservableArray<MyItem>> {
  return fetch(this.serverUrlGET)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((r) => {
      // r contain 5 elements
      let myItems = this.onGetDataSuccess(r); // the method onGetDataSuccess return an array of MyItem objects ==> MyItem[];
      console.log("Length of MyItems 1 = " + myItems.length);
      return new ObservableArray(myItems);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Dear Juan, doing as you suggest I'm immediately posted with the compilation error:
"Type 'Promise<void | ObservableArray<MyItem>>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ObservableArray<MyItem>>'.
  Type 'void | ObservableArray<MyItem>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableArray<MyItem>'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableArray<MyItem>'"

Comment: Updated the return type on the answer. I think that should fix the compilation error